# 2-combination without nested loop in C++ where the number of iterations is equal to the number of 2-combinations

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Here is a code sample that generates all possible 2-combination without repetition:

```
int datanum = 4;
    for (int arg = 0; arg < datanum*datanum; arg++)
    {
        int j = arg % datanum;
        int i = arg / datanum;

        if (i < j)
        {
            std::cout << "i=" << i << " j=" << j << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
i=0 j=1
i=0 j=2
i=0 j=3
i=1 j=2
i=1 j=3
i=2 j=3
```

My question is: How can I generate 2-combination without repetition by using only one loop where the number of iterations should be equal to the number of 2-combinations (in case of N=4 it should be 6 not 4*4=16 like in my current solution)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Isn't the output, already present in the question? The question, as I understand it, is about improving the algorithm (it takes 16 iterations at the moment, where it skips unnecessary entries, and the goal is so it takes exactly 6, and skips no entries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
int datanum = 4;
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
while (i < datanum-1) {
{
    std::cout << "i=" << i << " j=" << j << std::endl;
    j++
    if (j == datanum) {
        i++;
        j = i + 1;
    }
}
```